# Pinch and Zoom,Drag n Drop,Rotate Multiple Images in SingleView in Android

Tags: android, canvas, gestures, pinchzoom

I am trying to create an app which would allow me to add images to a view using button click . Once added the images could be scaled,dragged,rotated depending on the touch gestures individually . I tried out all codes available out there, like:
1.https://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html
2.//github.com/judepereira/android-multitouch
3.//github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors
4.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/multi-touch-panning-pinch-zoom-image-view-in-android-using/
5.//github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java
6.//www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android

In all above codes which worked great,I found one common thread that is they were implemented using Canvas and manipulated just one bitmap.I tried using canvas but that ensued another problem, How can I draw bitmaps to canvas dynamically, which would be like redrawing the canvas. I did try it but couldn't find a way to get reference to existing canvas object which is available only inside onDraw method while I needed to trigger the onDraw method from the parent Activity class. It would be great help if someone could guide me .

Comment: Is not easy what you want to achieve. You'll have to build yourself a sort of layers solution.

Comment: The workaround I found was to create a simple Layout and add images . But every time I scale an Image I have to re-adjust my imageview . I did achieve this but the image inside the Imageview always rests in the corner. While the rotate doesn't work that well . BTW @joaquin could you elaborate on that Layer solution ? Just the concept would suffice too .

Comment: Also the Image transitions on Layout are not as pleasing as you find on canvas so I am unable to decide whether to go for Canvas or Improve the existing Layout

Comment: The way to go is canvas, but I'd the hard way. You could make an array or a list of views and assign each view an on touch listener. And also you'll need to keep register of actual position of each view

Comment: I decided to try the surfaceView and I was able to draw bitmaps from the parent activity but every time I draw a new image the old image is erased.Is there API provided method to save the canvas state ? I did try save and restore though . The other way is as you mentioned creating an array of images and redrawing them for each update . This would make it very cumbersome . I doubt how much efficient way it is .